# Symfony 4 deploying as production or removing profiler access

Tags: bundle, symfony4, profiler

I am trying to disable profiler for my Symfony 4 production environment. I did that in config/packages/dev/web_profiler.php. Only my debug toolbar is hidden.

However, when I navigate the URL www.symfony4app.com/_profiler I could see all the information.

Is there any way, I can remove access to profiler completely in production ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you changed your configuration in `config/packages/dev/` and took effect, your application environment is not properly configured and currently running in the `dev` environment, since it determines how the application configuration gets loaded. From the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-environments).

> Symfony loads the configuration files in this order (the last files
>   can override the values set in the previous ones):
>
> ```
> config/packages/*.yaml
> config/packages/<environment-name>/*.yaml
> config/packages/services.yaml
> ```

You'll have to change the environment variable `APP_ENV` which in turn can be set in the `.env` file (or `.env.local` if it exists) or (preferably) in your server config.

The file `config/bundles.php` determines what bundles are available in which environment. If it's being loaded in `prod` you most likely have this line:

```
Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

Just change it to:

```
Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
```

Flex usually takes care of installing with proper configuration, but you can also add the package with `composer --dev` option and install with `--no-dev` in `prod`.